# Disable Node's Show summary in full view in D6

Tags: 6, nodes

In https://drupal.org/node/514318 it talks about how to disable showing the summary/teaser in full view mode but only for D7 it seems.

In my D6 based site, I've filled in meta-description in the node teaser as required by Nodewords module.

The problem is that in full view mode it is clubbing this node teaser with the node's body text. Is there any option to avoid it adding with the body content?

In the picture from dsm($form) in hook_form_alter when editing node we can see there is teaser_include array key with #default_value = TRUE. I'm wondering where in the Admin interface we can specify this setting.

[image]

Comment: If you goto `admin/content/node-type/NODETYPE/display` where `NODETYPE` is the actual node type you are talking about, you can specify what fields are displayed and how in the `$content` variable in node teasers and full views.  That's where I'd start looking first.

Comment: My question is different, how to avoid clubbing of teaser with node's body content. It isn't there in the display options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a form_alter function for node edit form that has solved my problem:

```
function my_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'page_node_form') {
        $form['body_field']['teaser_include']['#default_value'] = FALSE;

        $prefix = $form['#node']->teaser;
        $str = $form['body_field']['body']['#default_value'];

        if (substr($str, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
            $form['body_field']['body']['#default_value'] = substr($str, strlen($prefix));
        }

    }
}
```

Also the teaser_include as in the question is from the node edit form which is accessible from this checkbox:
[image]